# Kubuntu Desktop goes black

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

My desktop always crashes and becomes black everytime I use google chrome probably when I'm streaming or downloading. The latte dock is still there but the icons and top panel, also the desktop background is just nothing. Here is a screenshot of it. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: In Google Chrome's advanced settings, have you tried turning off hardware acceleration?